# How to use 'Which device did you plug in' dialog box

Tags: audio, microphone, dell-inspiron

I use a Dell laptop, and every time I plug in my earphones, this dialog box pops up:

[image: IMG:]

What do all these options do if I connect regular earphones with a mic in them?

Also, I want to use the mic on my earphones in online calls, but the output sound should come from the laptop speakers. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is the Dell Audio manager. It's an optional app that you can install on a Dell device. If you use lots of different types audio devices, it's a good idea to install it.

What it does:

The app makes it easier to identify and configure an audio device that you connect to the PC via the audio jack. The various options that you see e.g., mic in, line in etc, will allow you to use the device in various apps.

If you connect a headset with a mic and select 'Mic in', you will only be able to use the mic on your headset. If you select Line In, you will not be able to use the mic on the headset and your PC will instead continue to use the built-in mic.

If you connect a stand-alone mic to the jack, and select mic in, you will be able to use the mic for recording but any audio will still be output via the speakers on your system.

How to use it:

When you connect an audio device, select which option describes it best i.e., can it send input and receive output, is just for outputting audio, or is it just for inputting audio.

These options make it so you don't have to manually configure an audio device which, if you were to do it manually, will take time and some technical know-how.

Source: none other than that I have a Dell and I use all sorts of audio devices with it for recording etc.